# Poissons ratio for a 1x1x1 cube made into a 2xYxZ

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

Consider a 1x1x1 cube. It has a volume of 1. If the material is isotropic and the poissons ratio is 0.5 the volume should be conserved.

consider then I stretch one side so it has a length of 2. The remaining dimensions are then (2*X*sqrt(2)/2)*X*sqrt(2)/2 , if the volume is still to equal 1.

Applying the formula for poissons ratio:

Poissons ratio = lateral*strain*1/(longitudinal*strain)

Lateral strain = (sqrt(2)/2 - 1)/1

Longitudinal strain = (2 - 1)/1

poissons ratio = (sqrt(2)/2 - 1)/(2 - 1) = 0.29

Which is not 0,5. What is happening?

Thank you

ps sorry the equations are not in "proper" format. Don't know how to do that here yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence of a Poisson ratio of 1/2 and constant volume (i.e., incompressibility) holds only in the limit of infinitesimal strains. You posited a very large strain—100%—and as a result, the relation is strongly inaccurate.

You can prove this to yourself by calculating the volume change expected from a tensile strain in one direction and the corresponding Poisson-mediated contractile strains in the other two directions.

Comment: hmm yea I just tried with a strain elongation of 1.01 instead of 2. and it equaled almost 0.5. 
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Good check! You’re welcome.